# Did I get too good a confidence interval for Pearson's R using bootstrap on a very unbalanced data set?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, correlation

I can't find this type of bootstrap problem described anywhere, **where the data is so unbalanced**: 50 y-values vs 2500 values yielding 50 means that become the x's. Another thing: the 50 strata yielding the means are internally autocorrelated time series. The bootstrapped mean histograms looked mostly normal distributed.

**Problem 1**: I just can't intuit if the improvement in confidence interval is too good to be true when I bootstrap from all 2500 values instead of directly from the 50 x, y-pairs: A span of 0.39 improved to 0.039. I.e. 10 times narrower. It makes no sense when having only 50 y-values available - or does it? I started to doubt either the bootstrap in this context, or my own R-code *provided below*, or my theoretical understanding. Should I trust the result or is there a theoretical reason not to? (I have checked out a few papers and I know bootstrap is not always that precise and that better variants and methods exist for correlation CIs, e.g: [Confidence intervals for correlations when data are not normal](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758%2Fs13428-016-0702-8.pdf))

bootstrap directly on means: R = 0.608 ( 0.3878,  0.7790 )

bootstrap from underlying values: R = 0.608 ( 0.5916,  0.6290 )

**Problem 2:** Why is including all data better according to this experiment? I can reason it both ways:

(Wrong way) Say I bootstrap from 50 fix y-values, and 50 X's that are averages. Then I have fix x-values with no variation and should get a narrower CI than if I introduce an uncertainty - a spread in each x average - by using all 2500 values.

(correct by experiment) On the other hand: Say I use all 2500 values in a two-step bootstrap computing first the mean and from it the x,y-correlation. Then I use more information than is inherent in the 50 x-averages, and should get a narrower confidence interval for the Pearson correlation.

I expected the second method to yield narrower confidence interval for Pearson's R since more information is utilized, but I don't know how or why and I am curious.

This is not commercial in any way. I help out a friend that is about to publish a paper I believe could be beneficial to general health. I benefit from it myself mostly by learning R (yes I am an R and Tidyverse newbie), and by the thrill of doing some real science for a good cause. I am a system developer by profession.

Here is the R code for using all data, with the unnecessaries removed:

```
testst <-function(tb,i) {
  # Generate correlation between yStrat and xStrat.
  # arg: tibble with about 2500 rows with about 50 strata 
  
  tbi <- tb[i, ] # Bootstrap sample
  
  yTbi <- tbi %>% group_by(StratumID) %>% 
    summarise(yStrat=last(YPrevalence)) # All Y identical per stratum
                                        # Could have used unique as well 
  # Apply mean to each stratum of bootstrapped draws from stratum
  xTbi <- tbi %>% group_by(StratumID) %>%
      summarise(xStrat = mean(XConsumption, na.rm = TRUE)) 

  # Apply cor to fixed y values against each stratum mean
  pears <- cor(x = xTbi$xStrat,
                 y = yTbi$yStrat,
                 method = "pearson")

  return(c(pears))
}

# Executing on tibble tbd with ~2500 rows, ~50 strata. One fix Y-value per stratum
tbd$StratumID <- as_factor(tbd$StratumID)
bt <- boot(tbd,testst,R=10000,strata=tbd$StratumID)
bc<-boot.ci(bt,type="bca",index=1)
```

Comment: You probably want to bootstrap the *residuals* rather than the raw data; this will help preserve the structure of the data, at the cost of some additional assumptions. Furthermore, if you want to deal with the temporal autocorrelation you will probably need a *block bootstrap*.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @ben-bolker! Your answer led me to this paper: [Estimating Pearson’s Correlation Coefficient With Bootstrap Confidence Interval From Serially Dependent Time Series](https://www.manfredmudelsee.com/publ/pdf/Estimating_Pearson_correlation_coefficient_with_bootstrap_confidence_interval_from_serially_dependent_time_series.pdf). It confirms that the effective sample size I have is in reality much reduced due to the autocorrelation, as I suspected. I think I can adapt the method by using block bootstrap on each individual time series.
I will look up bootstrapping residuals as well when I get the time.

(Btw: my question was migrated to this forum and it seems I do not own it anymore - "You have not asked any questions" - so I could not just add a comment due to lack of "reputation")